# Is consistency in routine structure important?

Tags: coding-style, structure

I have heard that having consistent naming, formatting, and commenting conventions is useful. I have also heard that being consistent with a design pattern is useful.

However, I have not heard that having consistent structures on the routine level is useful. For example, if a program has the routines `foo(bar, norf)` and `baz(bar, qux)`, is it good  for `baz`'s parameters or arguments to be ordered [`bar`, `qux`] instead of [`qux`, `bar`] in order to be consistent about the location of `bar` in the two routines' interfaces?

As another example, if both `foo` and `baz` call `fum` and it does not matter when `fum` is called, is it best for both `foo` and `baz` to call it at the same location, e.g. both at the start of the routine or both at the end?

I predict this consistency is be useful, because it is essentially what parallelism in writing is, which improves readability, but I am unsure.

So, is consistency in the structure of routines useful?

Answer (score 0):

I've been reviewing *Code Complete*, and it said:

> The more a system relies on exotic pieces, the more intimidating it will be for
>   someone trying to understand it the first time. Try to give the whole system a
>   familiar feeling by using standardized, common approaches.

Being consistent is useful for being standard and normal. Thus, the answer is presumably yes: consistency is useful.